# Ansilbe AWX python error ansible.plugins.callback.awx_display.CallbackModule

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-awx

I am getting error while running a playbook from ansible AWX tower. How can i fix this?

from CLI it works but not from ansible AWX

playbook

```
    - name: play1
      ansible.netcommon.telnet:
        user: aaaaaaaa
        password: bbbbbbbb
        login_prompt: "login: "
        password_prompt: "Password:"
        prompts:
          - '[>]'
        command:
          - ping {{item.ips}} count 15
      loop: "{{ IPADDRESS }}"
```

```
IPADDRESS:
  - ips: 'google.com'
  - ips: '8.8.8.8'
```

I am running AWX 15.0.1 Ansible 2.9.14

```
[WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_item_on_ok) in callback plugin
(<ansible.plugins.callback.awx_display.CallbackModule object at
0x7f97c9845cf8>): Object of type 'AnsibleUnsafeBytes' is not JSON serializable
```

```
PLAY [pay1] ****************************************************
META: ran handlers

[WARNING]: Failure using method (v2_runner_item_on_ok) in callback plugin
(<ansible.plugins.callback.awx_display.CallbackModule object at
0x7f97c9845cf8>): Object of type 'AnsibleUnsafeBytes' is not JSON serializable


Callback Exception: 
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible/executor/task_queue_manager.py", line 327, in send_callback
    method(*new_args, **kwargs)
   File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_runner/display_callback/module.py", line 495, in v2_runner_item_on_ok
    with self.capture_event_data('runner_item_on_ok', **event_data):
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
   File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_runner/display_callback/module.py", line 100, in capture_event_data
    event_context.dump_begin(sys.stdout)
   File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_runner/display_callback/events.py", line 196, in dump_begin
    self.cache.set(":1:ev-{}".format(begin_dict['uuid']), begin_dict)
   File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_runner/display_callback/events.py", line 71, in set
    partial_data = json.dumps(value, cls=AnsibleJSONEncoderLocal)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 238, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
   File "/var/lib/awx/venv/awx/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_runner/display_callback/events.py", line 51, in default
    return super(AnsibleJSONEncoderLocal, self).default(o)
   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/json/encoder.py", line 180, in default
    o.__class__.__name__)
```

Comment: You can fix it by [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65878090/edit) and converting it to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at bare minimum including the failing playbook task. No one can _guess_ what is wrong with your setup aside from a lack of `| string` on some expression

Comment: @mdaniel i have edited question , added playbook

Comment: Interesting; seems [their custom deserializer](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/blob/devel/ansible_runner/display_callback/events.py#L37) needs [to be updated for AnsibleUnsafeText](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71307#issuecomment-674933685) -- all I know to do is [open an issue with them](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/issues), or you can try `no_log: yes` on that task to see if it's _just_ `telnet:` or is a bigger bug. I regrettably wasn't able to reproduce it locally, partially because I don't know everything that generates `UnsafeText`